# How to Assign Different IP Address to Different Application

Tags: windows, ip

I need a software or any scripting to assign different IP Address to Different Application.

For Example,

At the same time,
Chrome -> X.X.X.1
Mozzila -> X.X.X.2
IE -> X.X.X.3

Comment: I was also wanting to know about the software which could do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the IP adress is on a per network adapter level, so each ethernet or wireless adapter can only have 1 So it is not possible to do manually i think  run a bit of software that allows you to force bind an ip address to an application.: http://old.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/  may work try that